# Remove Laravel/Vue bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to combine an HTML template with Vue and Laravel, so I can add more functionalities to it. Everything works fine but the template CSS is messed up, like if Vue or Laravel are having precedence over the template CSS. Is there any way to remove the CSS part that comes with Vue/Laravel? The template alone works perfectly, but when combined with Laravel project, it gets messed up.

Comment: are u using webpack to compile everything down?

Comment: No, I'm not using it.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply remove everything from the `resources/sass/app.scss` file.

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal type

```
  php artisan preset none
```

It will remove Vue.js and Bootstrap from your application.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend

Comment: I've already tried that. It removes all my Vue part, not what I need.

Comment: Did you tried to install Vue after The above command? npm install vue vue-router

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for laravel 7.x and above. The command `preset` no longer exists. When trying different combinations to make `php artisan ui <type> --auth` work without installing react, vue, or bootstrap, I realized what the error actually meant and how the source code is written. Looks like there's no choice but to choose one of the three options. Take a look at the source code snippet below. This means there's no option for entering something like `php artisan ui none --auth`. Additionally, entering `php artisan ui vue --auth` or `php artisan ui react --auth` installs bootstrap as well as the UI framework.

```
         if (! in_array($this->argument('type'), ['bootstrap', 'vue', 'react'])) {
  > 41|             throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid preset.');
    42|         }
```